# Html dropdown not overlaying on top of other webpage elements

Tags: html, css, sass

Before posting this question, I have looked into various stack overflow questions and implemented them but it didn't work for me.

Please do not post this question as duplicate.

My problem is that my dropdown is not coming on top of other elements.

I have posted the code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f6p2km4b/)

NOTE: Please drag the output window towards the left to get the proper view of the header

In the SCSS window, user profile dropdown is handled by class navbarDropdown

```
.navbarDropdown {
  float: right;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  position: relative;

  img {
    margin-top: -5px;
    height: 40px;
  }

  ul {
    background-color: $base-secondary-color;
    padding: 4px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: auto;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 1px;
  }

  ul a {
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 40px 0 10px;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

I have tried position:absoulute and z-index.

I don't know where is the mistake. Any help is appreciated?

Comment: so you want logo, menu bar in left and balance,  user profile and add funds to the right. If screen is small then right panel will be in second row, right?

Comment: I did not add the responsive classes. I just needed to know why the dropdown  was not working. But now it's working after Jason's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of it, the reason your drop down list is hidden is because it overflows the content of the nav element, ".navbar". Adding the CSS property overflow: visible; should fix the immediate problem.